# Python Selenium | Get span text

Tags: python, html, selenium

How can I get the text of a span "-3" with selenium?

[image: Picture]

Comment: In case an answer helped you, please consider upvoting and accepting it! Obviously, there is no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to access the element itself. To achieve that you can use [various](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) `find` methods:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("mjx-char MJXc-TeX-main-R")
```

Now you can grasp the text of said element:

```
text = element.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply grab the span class with the previously mentioned tags and use .text.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.mjx-char.MJXc-TeX-main-R")
print(element.text)
```

Comment: So Now I get an Error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.mjx-char.MJXc-TeX-main-R"}

Comment: Is it any iframes?

Comment: I dont really know what you mean, because im new into programming, but here is the outer layer of the code, the -3 has changed into 4 because it's random:

<span id="MJXc-Node-5" class="mjx-mn"><span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-main-R" style="padding-top: 0.408em; padding-bottom: 0.35em;">4</span></span>